# Overflow of List-Based ListView

Tags: scroll, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to preface this question by saying that I am very new to flutter/dart.

Essentially, I have a list containing a bunch of strings. I want to list them in the main (and only) view. I have this code:

```
ListView(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
  children: _availableTraits.map((item) => new Text(item, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0))).toList()
  )
```

I guess I am fortunate that `_availableTraits` is a relatively large list so that I discovered this problem. The list goes beyond the bottom of the page and a sort of warning/caution tape is put up at the bottom of the screen by flutter along with the error message: `BOTTOM OVERFLOWED BY 93 PIXELS`.

So how can I force flutter to just use a scroll bar?

Edit:

Figured I should probably share a picture of the problem.
[image: Failed Scroll: yellow/black stripes]

Edit 2:

The above `ListView` is wrapped in a `column` element. The `column` element is wrapped in a `scaffold`.

Comment: have you tried wrapping it with `SafeArea`?

Comment: it's working fine here, could you add more code?

Comment: @MichaelYuwono Sorry for noob question, but how would I do that? Just `SafeArea(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix your issue you need to expand your shrinked `ListView`, like this:

```
  Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                ...
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you very much! What's the difference between `ListView` and `ListView.builder`? Is it a best practice/convention, and/or a tangible benefit? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: ListView.builder helps you when you have a lot of items and you want to generate the items dynamically , for more info you can check here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html